# are there any other deep learning approaches other than Mask R-CNN for detection and segmentation of buildings from satellite images

Tags: machine-learning

recently I read a paper where I found the statement that for detection and segmentation of buildings from satellite images can only be done by Mask R-CNN and no other algorithm can be used as the problem is only suitable for Mask R-CNN. is it true? because I have lot of doubts.
and cant we use YOLO or U-NET deep learning methods in this type of problems.
can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: this reminds me of a paper I read declaring there were no algorithms or approaches available to accurately determine the notes played on a specific musical instrument, based on the input of some sampled soundwave. I promptly developed a neural network with feedback loops in C language on an old Intel x86 PC in the late 90s and trained it to spit out notes of whatever I sampled on a range of instruments. Lesson? Ignore anything that says it can't be done. It can.

Comment: thank you so much for your response. the work you have done is remarkable. if your work is documented could you possibly share the link of the article or paper. maybe?

Comment: I have no evidence, other than a few friends who could confirm it. I was not part of any academia at that time. On the contrary we rejected academia in order to advance.

Comment: oh okay. what you are trying to tell me is never look into one side. There are other sides present too? all I have to do is get deeper into it.

Comment: according to you we could actually use YOLO or U-NET in the detection and segmentation of building from satellite images.? from the sources available online.. segmentation cant be done with YOLO. but I don't know about U-NET. I kinda need to find an explanation to my own question here.